# Boleto Bancário - Converter Código de Barras em Linha Digitável

Tags: java, conversão, pagamento-online

Estou fazendo a leitura de código de barras de boleto bancário, mas descobri que o código de barras não corresponde exatamente (numericamente) à linha digitável (também chamada de código de linha, código numérico ou IPTE).

Conforme um documento do Banco do Brasil:

> [*4. Linha Digitável – Representação Numérica do Código de Barras:*
>
>   __ *4.1. O dados da linha digitável não se apresentam na mesma sequência dos dados do código de barras.*](http://www.bb.com.br/docs/pub/emp/empl/dwn/Doc5175Bloqueto.pdf)

**Portanto preciso de uma documentação ou implementação para conseguir converter o Código de Barras em Linha Digitável.**

Esta página faz a conversão em Javascript:
http://evandro.net/codigo_barras.html
(caso não encontre uma conversão oficial, farei a conversão a partir deste javascript)

Comment: Em qual linguagem de programação você precisa?

Comment: Estou fazendo em Java. (encontrei essa referência: http://www.ttrix.com/apple/iphone/boletoscan/boletoanatomia.html)

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa projeto aqui: https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando a conversão do Javascript desta página (http://evandro.net/codigo_barras.html) cheguei ao código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calculaLinha("39993000000000014993739040736027668911000002"));
}

public static String calculaLinha(String barra) {
    // Remover caracteres não numéricos.
    String linha = barra.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

    if (linha.length() != 44) {
        return null; // 'A linha do Código de Barras está incompleta!'
    }

    String campo1 = linha.substring(0,4)+linha.substring(19,20)+'.'+linha.substring(20,24);
    String campo2 = linha.substring(24,29)+'.'+linha.substring(29,34);
    String campo3 = linha.substring(34,39)+'.'+linha.substring(39,44);
    String campo4 = linha.substring(4,5); // Digito verificador
    String campo5 = linha.substring(5,19); // Vencimento + Valor

    if (  modulo11Banco(  linha.substring(0,4)+linha.substring(5,44)  ) != Integer.valueOf(campo4) ) {
        return null; //'Digito verificador '+campo4+', o correto é '+modulo11_banco(  linha.substr(0,4)+linha.substr(5,99)  )+'\nO sistema não altera automaticamente o dígito correto na quinta casa!'
    }
    return   campo1 + modulo10(campo1)
            +' '
            +campo2 + modulo10(campo2)
            +' '
            +campo3 + modulo10(campo3)
            +' '
            +campo4
            +' '
            +campo5
            ;
}

public static int modulo10(String numero) {
    numero = numero.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
    int soma  = 0;
    int peso  = 2;
    int contador = numero.length()-1;
    while (contador >= 0) {
        int multiplicacao = Integer.valueOf( numero.substring(contador,contador+1) ) * peso;
        if (multiplicacao >= 10) {multiplicacao = 1 + (multiplicacao-10);}
        soma = soma + multiplicacao;
        if (peso == 2) {
            peso = 1;
        } else {
            peso = 2;
        }
        contador = contador - 1;
    }
    int digito = 10 - (soma % 10);
    if (digito == 10) digito = 0;

    return digito;
}

public static int modulo11Banco(String numero) {
    numero = numero.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");

    int soma  = 0;
    int peso  = 2;
    int base  = 9;
    int contador = numero.length() - 1;
    for (int i=contador; i >= 0; i--) {
        soma = soma + ( Integer.valueOf(numero.substring(i,i+1)) * peso);
        if (peso < base) {
            peso++;
        } else {
            peso = 2;
        }
    }
    int digito = 11 - (soma % 11);
    if (digito >  9) digito = 0;
    /* Utilizar o dígito 1(um) sempre que o resultado do cálculo padrão for igual a 0(zero), 1(um) ou 10(dez). */
    if (digito == 0) digito = 1;
    return digito;
}
```

**não efetuei nenhuma otimização no código para o Java**, apenas fiz apenas validação o algoritmo [deste link](http://www.ttrix.com/apple/iphone/boletoscan/boletoanatomia.html).

Comment: A resposta já está ai. Só fiz a conversão agora para php e coloquei a solução em javascript, porque o site do evandro está fora do ar (achei no webarchives por sorte) http://aia.la/blog/converter_linha_digitavel_codigo_barra Download direto do arquivo: http://samuca.com/l/lCq4

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira, ainda tens o código javascript original do Evandro? Em caso afirmativo, poderia deixar o link para download? obrigado.

Comment: Também estou procurando o código original em JavaScript

Answer (score 14):

Uma descrição completa da relação entre os dois formatos pode ser encontrada aqui:

[Qual a diferença do código de barras FEBRABAN lido para o digitado?](http://www.rogetechbrasil.com.br/suporte/knowledge-base/bid/126276/Qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-do-c%C3%B3digo-de-barras-FEBRABAN-lido-para-o-digitado) por [Leonardo Calandriello](http://www.rogetechbrasil.com.br/suporte/knowledge-base/?Author=Leonardo%20Calandriello). Copio o conteúdo relevante aqui para evitar links inválidos futuros:

> [...] os dados (números) contidos na linha digitável representam sim o
>   conteúdo do código de barras, porém dispostos em uma ordem diferente e
>   acrescidos do dígito verificador nos 3 primeiros campos. Veja a tabela
>   abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Em cada um dos três primeiros campos, após a 5ª posição, deve ser
>   inserido um ponto“.”, afim de facilitar a visualização para a
>   digitação, quando necessário;
>
> Quinto campo: deve ser preenchido com
>   zeros entre o fator de vencimento e o valor até completar 14
>   posições; se existir 4 zeros em sequencia “0000” no campo “fator de
>   vencimento” da linha digitável, o código de barras não contém fator de
>   vencimento.
>
> Os dígitos verificadores referentes aos 1º, 2º e 3º campos não são
>   representados no código de barras. O total de de dígitos na linha
>   então será de 47, diferente do código que contem apenas 44 dígitos.
>   Alguns leitores mostram na tela o conteúdo do código, isso acontece
>   pois eles tem a habilidade de converter o código lido.

<sub>[Edit-disclaimer] Esta resposta considera a primeira versão desta pergunta, onde a linguagem destino não era especificada.</sub>

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado! Estava procurando a conversão direta do código numérico do código de barras para a linha digitável. Este link foi um dos que tinham esclarecido a diferença, mas ele é útil para extrair as informações do código de barras.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei nesse site https://boletobancario-codigodebarras.blogspot.com/ o código em **JavaScript** que converte o código de barras para linha digitável e vice-versa:

```
function f_barra() {
    var antes  = form.barra.value;
    var depois = calcula_barra(form.linha.value);
    form.barra.value=depois;
    antes = antes.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')
    if ((antes != depois) && antes != '') alert('O código de barras digitado não confere:\n'+antes+'\n'+depois);
    f_venc();
    return(false);
}

function f_linha() {
    var antes  = form.linha.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    var depois = calcula_linha(form.barra.value);
    form.linha.value=depois;
    depois = depois.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')
    if ((antes != depois) && antes != '') alert('O código de barras digitado não confere:\n'+antes+'\n'+depois);
    f_venc();
    return(false);
}

function f_venc() {
    if ( form.barra.value.substr(5,4) == 0 )
        form.venc.value='O boleto pode ser pago em qualquer data';
    else
        form.venc.value=fator_vencimento(form.barra.value.substr(5,4));
    form.valor.value=(form.barra.value.substr(9,8)*1)+','+form.barra.value.substr(17,2);
    return(false);
}

function calcula_barra(linha)
{
    //var linha = form.linha.value; // Linha Digitável
    barra  = linha.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    //
    // CÁLCULO DO DÍGITO DE AUTO CONFERÊNCIA (DAC)   -   5ª POSIÇÃO
    if (modulo11_banco('34191000000000000001753980229122525005423000') != 1) alert('Função "modulo11_banco" está com erro!');
    //
    //if (barra.length == 36) barra = barra + '00000000000';
    if (barra.length < 47 ) barra = barra + '00000000000'.substr(0,47-barra.length);
    if (barra.length != 47) alert ('A linha do código de barras está incompleta!'+barra.length);
    //
    barra  = barra.substr(0,4)
            +barra.substr(32,15)
            +barra.substr(4,5)
            +barra.substr(10,10)
            +barra.substr(21,10)
            ;
    //form.barra.value = barra;
    if (modulo11_banco(barra.substr(0,4)+barra.substr(5,39)) != barra.substr(4,1))
        alert('Digito verificador '+barra.substr(4,1)+', o correto é '+modulo11_banco(barra.substr(0,4)+barra.substr(5,39))+'\nO sistema não altera automaticamente o dígito correto na quinta casa!');
    //if (form.barra.value != form.barra2.value) alert('Barras diferentes');
    return(barra);
}

function calcula_linha(barra)
{
    //var barra = form.barra.value; // Codigo da Barra
    linha = barra.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    //
    if (modulo10('399903512') != 8) alert('Função "modulo10" está com erro!');
    if (linha.length != 44) alert ('A linha do código de barras está incompleta!');
    //
    var campo1 = linha.substr(0,4)+linha.substr(19,1)+'.'+linha.substr(20,4);
    var campo2 = linha.substr(24,5)+'.'+linha.substr(24+5,5);
    var campo3 = linha.substr(34,5)+'.'+linha.substr(34+5,5);
    var campo4 = linha.substr(4,1);     // Digito verificador
    var campo5 = linha.substr(5,14);    // Vencimento + Valor
    //
    if (  modulo11_banco(  linha.substr(0,4)+linha.substr(5,99)  ) != campo4 )
        alert('Digito verificador '+campo4+', o correto é '+modulo11_banco(  linha.substr(0,4)+linha.substr(5,99)  )+'\nO sistema não altera automaticamente o dígito correto na quinta casa!');
    //
    if (campo5 == 0) campo5 = '000';
    //
    linha =  campo1 + modulo10(campo1)
            +' '
            +campo2 + modulo10(campo2)
            +' '
            +campo3 + modulo10(campo3)
            +' '
            +campo4
            +' '
            +campo5
            ;
    //if (form.linha.value != form.linha2.value) alert('Linhas diferentes');
    return(linha);
}

function fator_vencimento (dias) {
    //Fator contado a partir da data base 07/10/1997
    //*** Ex: 31/12/2011 fator igual a = 5198
    //alert(dias);
    var currentDate, t, d, mes;
    t = new Date();
    currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setFullYear(1997,9,7);//alert(currentDate.toLocaleString());
    t.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * dias));//alert(t.toLocaleString());
    mes = (currentDate.getMonth()+1); if (mes < 10) mes = "0" + mes;
    dia = (currentDate.getDate()+1); if (dia < 10) dia = "0" + dia;
    //campo.value = dia +"."+mes+"."+currentDate.getFullYear();campo.select();campo.focus();
    return(t.toLocaleString());
}

function modulo10(numero)
{

    numero = numero.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    var soma  = 0;
    var peso  = 2;
    var contador = numero.length-1;
    //alert(contador);
    //numero = '00183222173';
    //for (var i=0; i <= contador - 1; i++) {
    //alert(10);
    //for (contador=10; contador >= 10 - 1; contador--) {
    while (contador >= 0) {
        //alert(contador);
        //alert(numero.substr(contador,1));
        multiplicacao = ( numero.substr(contador,1) * peso );
        if (multiplicacao >= 10) {multiplicacao = 1 + (multiplicacao-10);}
        soma = soma + multiplicacao;
        //alert(numero.substr(contador,1)+' * '+peso+' = '+multiplicacao + ' =>' + soma) ;
        //alert(soma);
        if (peso == 2) {
            peso = 1;
        } else {
            peso = 2;
        }
        contador = contador - 1;
    }
    var digito = 10 - (soma % 10);
    //alert(numero + '\n10 - (' + soma + ' % 10) = ' + digito);
    if (digito == 10) digito = 0;
    return digito;
}


function modulo11_banco(numero)
{

    numero = numero.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    //debug('Barra: '+numero);
    var soma  = 0;
    var peso  = 2;
    var base  = 9;
    var resto = 0;
    var contador = numero.length - 1;
    //debug('tamanho:'+contador);
    // var numero = "12345678909";
    for (var i=contador; i >= 0; i--) {
        //alert( peso );
        soma = soma + ( numero.substring(i,i+1) * peso);
        //debug( i+': '+numero.substring(i,i+1) + ' * ' + peso + ' = ' +( numero.substring(i,i+1) * peso)+' soma='+ soma);
        if (peso < base) {
            peso++;
        } else {
            peso = 2;
        }
    }
    var digito = 11 - (soma % 11);
    //debug( '11 - ('+soma +'%11='+(soma % 11)+') = '+digito);
    if (digito >  9) digito = 0;

    if (digito == 0) digito = 1;
     return digito;
    }
```

Comment: Sabe informar porque se o tamanho da linha é menor que 47 ele autocompleta até com 11 zeros?