# Código de barra de uma conta de consumo

Tags: android, ios, brasil, código-de-barras

Quando eu faço o pagamento de uma conta de consumo (água, luz, telefone), o banco me mostra o nome da operadora, valor, etc.

Como faço para saber quais são exatamente esses campos e como (alguma biblioteca) poderia lê-los e obter o nome da operadora e qual o tipo de conta, banco, etc?

Comment: A princípio, [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27139/4337) pode te ajudar na identificação dos campos da linha digitável. Com essas informações você já consegue desenvolver algo para isso mas como você especificou as duas plataformas, a resposta talvez seria um pouco ampla. Particularmente não conheço uma biblioteca pronta para que faça isso.

Comment: A Febraban, instituição responsável pela Federação dos Bancos no Brasil possui layout padrão nos códigos de barras dos boletos bancários. Para mais detalhes das linhas digitáveis/códigos de barras, recomendo estes artigos:
http://informacaocomdiversao.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/entendendo-como-formada-linha-digitvel.html
http://boletobancario-codigodebarras.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/desvendando-os-segredos-do-boleto.html Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para boletos de arrecadação, como são chamados pela Febraban é utilizado o
`Layout - Código de Barras - Versão 5 - 01.08.2016`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
LAY OUT
POSIÇÃO TAMANHO CONTEÚDO
01 – 01 1 Identificação do Produto
02 – 02 1 Identificação do Segmento
03 – 03 1 Identificação do valor real ou referência
04 – 04 1 Dígito verificador geral (módulo 10 ou 11)
05 – 15 11 Valor
16 – 19 4 Identificação da Empresa/Órgão
20 – 44 25 Campo livre de utilização da Empresa/Órgão
16 – 23 8 CNPJ / MF
24 – 44 21 Campo livre de utilização da Empresa/Órgão
```

Achei importante isso aqui também:

```
Identificação do Produto Constante “8” para identificar arrecadação
Identificação do Segmento Identificará o segmento e a forma de identificação da Empresa/Órgão:
    1. Prefeituras;
    2. Saneamento;
    3. Energia Elétrica e Gás;
    4. Telecomunicações;
    5. Órgãos Governamentais;
    6. Carnes e Assemelhados ou demais
    Empresas / Órgãos que serão identificadas através do CNPJ.
    7. Multas de trânsito
    9. Uso exclusivo do banco
```

Retirado de [Layout - Código de Barras - Versão 5 - 01.08.2016](https://cmsportal.febraban.org.br/Arquivos/documentos/PDF/Layout%20-%20C%C3%B3digo%20de%20Barras%20-%20Vers%C3%A3o%205%20-%2001_08_2016.pdf)

Comment: Link atualizado para [Layout - Código de Barras - Versão 5 - 01.08.2016](https://cmsarquivos.febraban.org.br/Arquivos/documentos/PDF/Layout%20-%20C%C3%B3digo%20de%20Barras%20-%20Vers%C3%A3o%205%20-%2001_08_2016.pdf). Link para o [Layout - Código de Barras - Versão 6 - 22.06.2020](https://cmsarquivos.febraban.org.br/Arquivos/documentos/PDF/Layout%20-%20C%C3%B3digo%20de%20Barras%20ATUALIZADO.pdf)